# Regex Look Behind Limit in R

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to extract the numeric value (Items with Bold font) present next to the "High" keyword in the below text. But I am getting an error as

> "Error in stri_extract_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
>     Look-Behind pattern matches must have a bounded maximum length. (U_REGEX_LOOK_BEHIND_LIMIT)"

The regex that I used is

```
"(?<=High\\s*>?=?\\s?)[\\d\\.]+[\\s\\-\\d\\.]+(?=\\s)").
```

This works in the regex tester online but when I do the same in Rstudio, I get the above error

> 

The text is

```
 Optimal             <2.6  Desirable           2.6 - 3.3  Borderline high     3.4 - 4.0  High                ***4.1 - 4.8***  Very high           >=4.9

 Desirable       <5.2  Borderline high 5.2 - 6.1  High            >= ***6.2***

 Desirable   <1.7  Borderline High 1.7 - 2.2  High      ***2.3 - 4.4***  Very high >=4.5
```

Please note that I have used double slashes as it's in R language. However here in SO, it shows only one slash

Can you help me?

Comment: Look-behind expresions work best when they are of a fixed length. i.e. no `+` or `*` in the `(?<= )` bit. Also, can you provide an expected output so we can see what you want to get?

Comment: Hi, I would like to see the output in 3 rows  Row 1--> 4.1 - 4.8      Row2 --> 6.2  Row3--> 2.3-4.4

Comment: @Rohit why is taht? I dont quiet get why you cant use `+` or `*` in a look behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**sample data**

I changed one 'Borderline High' to 'Borderline high'. Assumed typo.

```
v <- c("Optimal             <2.6  Desirable           2.6 - 3.3  Borderline high     3.4 - 4.0  High                4.1 - 4.8  Very high           >=4.9",
       "Desirable       <5.2  Borderline high 5.2 - 6.1  High            >= 6.2",
         "Desirable   <1.7  Borderline high 1.7 - 2.2  High      2.3 - 4.4  Very high >=4.5")
```

**code**

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data.frame( text = v, stringsAsFactors = FALSE ) %>%
  #Extract text between "High" and "Very", trim whirespace
  dplyr::mutate( High = trimws( stringr::str_extract(text, "(?<=High).*(?=Very)") ) ) %>%
  #If no text was extracted, take everything after "High" until the end
  dplyr::mutate( High = ifelse( is.na( High ), trimws( stringr::str_extract(text, "(?<=High).*(?=$)") ), High ) ) %>%
  dplyr::select( High )
```

**output**

```
#        High
# 1 4.1 - 4.8
# 2    >= 6.2
# 3 2.3 - 4.4
```

## update

Only take the values after `High`, if `High` is **not** preceeded by `[a-zA-Z]` .

```
data.frame( text = v, stringsAsFactors = FALSE ) %>%
  #Extract text between "High" and "Very", trim whirespace
  dplyr::mutate( High = trimws( stringr::str_extract(text, "(?<=[^a-zA-Z] High).*(?=Very)") ) ) %>%
  #If no text was extracted, take everything after "High" until the end
  dplyr::mutate( High = ifelse( is.na( High ), trimws( stringr::str_extract(text, "(?<=[^a-zA-Z] High).*(?=$)") ), High ) ) %>%
  dplyr::select( High )
```

> ```
>        High
> 1 4.1 - 4.8
> 2    >= 6.2
> 3 2.3 - 4.4
> ```

Comment: Can you please let me know the regex without modifying the text. It isn't a typo and the actual term is "Borderline High". It has a upper case H. How do we do in this case?